# Why is my google API key breaking after 100 requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, google-maps, google-api

I'm validating addresses to make sure they exist. I'm using the google API to do this. I have a google API key and it works great.... until I go over 100. At request 110 I get this

```
{
  candidates: [],
  error_message: 'You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account',
  status: 'REQUEST_DENIED'
}
```

All I'm doing is looping through a list of addresses. It works perfectly up until then. And it's always at the exact same point.

I've tried slowing it down (thinking i'm making too many requests too quickly) by wrapping it in a while loop and only doing 50 at a time, but all that does it slow it down but still crashes at exactly 110.

Any ideas why or how or how to fix it? It is an unpaid API key if that helps (wondering if they have a request limit, I can't find anything saying they do)

Comment: please edit your question and include your code i would like to see how you are applying that api key.

Answer (score 1):

While it seems most likely that you have reached the quota allowed on an non-billing account, the status code should read `"OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"` which indicates that you are over your quota, rather than `"REQUEST_DENIED"`, which you are getting.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#StatusCodes

Further down, on the same page you have a suggestion as to the likely cause:

> "REQUEST_DENIED" indicates that the request was denied. Possibly because the >request includes a result_type or location_type parameter but does not include an >API key or client ID.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up a billing account.

Comment: can you expand on that? like the free version has limitations or?? i can't find any information on limitations

Comment: Read https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage-and-billing might help.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be one of the parameters I was sending to it had a special character that was breaking it. I printed out the URL before sending it to see what was going on.

TLDR had to use encodeURIComponent on the addresses I was sending, before sending them